# datetime in pandas showing the wrong value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime

**Made variables assigned with the time:**
year_= 2019
month_= 8
day_= 7
hour_= 6
sec_= 15

time_= datetime(year_,month_,day_,hour_,sec_)

**But when i call time_.second it returns 0 in jupyter notebook**

time_.second
0

Comment: side note: if you're working with pandas, use `pd.Timestamp`, not native Python datetime

Comment: @FObersteiner why should i use Timestamp instead of datetime is it better?

Comment: while you can use various sources as input (objects representing date / time), pandas will try to use the built-in datetime type to offer you best functionality (e.g. dt accessor for a datetime Series). See also [timeseries guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html) from the docs. Specifically for this case, you avoid a conversion from vanilla Python datetime to pandas datetime64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the 5th number is minutes. Not seconds.

Try:

```
year_= 2019
month_= 8
day_= 7
hour_= 6
min_ = 34
sec_= 15

time_= datetime(year_,month_,day_,hour_,min_,sec_)
time_.second
15
```

I have added the figure for minutes.